# How to display posts category in wordpress using tabbing?

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the categories that i have created in my post's in tabs i.e in tabbing like jquery tabbing.

Comment: I want to display these dynamic not using any code..So is there any plugin available or other way to display these categories

Comment: ask Google, he is your best friend